# PinchGesture and maximum, minimum limit

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipinchgesturerecognizer

I tried to set the maximum and minimum limit of PinchGesture.
But still have the problem of getting very small to almost disappeared or becomes very big and disappeared. What could be wrong with my code? I want to be two times bigger than the original size is the maximum limit and 0.7 times smaller than the original size is the minimum limit.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    imageMaxscale = 2;
    imageMinscale = 0.7;
    imageNormalscale = 1;

    UIPinchGestureRecognizer *pinchRecognizerdrawChart =
        [[UIPinchGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self
                                                 action:@selector(handlePinchRecognizerdrawChart:)];
    [pinchRecognizerdrawChart setDelegate:self];
    [self.drawChart addGestureRecognizer:pinchRecognizerdrawChart];

}

-(void)handlePinchRecognizerdrawChart:(UIPinchGestureRecognizer*)sender {
    if(imageNormalscale * [sender scale]  > imageMinscale && imageNormalscale * [sender scale]  < imageMaxscale){
        imageNormalscale = imageNormalscale * [sender scale];

        sender.view.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(sender.view.transform, imageNormalscale, imageNormalscale);

    }
    sender.scale = 1.0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the above solution from a link and it works in his demonstration. But doesn't work at my implementation. So I just modified as

```
-(void)handlePinchRecognizerdrawChart:(UIPinchGestureRecognizer*)sender {
    [self.scrollView bringSubviewToFront:self.drawChart];
    if([sender scale] > previouscale && self.drawChart.frame.size.width < screenRect.size.width*1.75){
        sender.view.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(sender.view.transform, [sender scale], [sender scale]);
        previouscale = [sender scale];
    }else if([sender scale] < previouscale && self.drawChart.frame.size.width > screenRect.size.width){
        sender.view.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(sender.view.transform, [sender scale], [sender scale]);
        previouscale = [sender scale];
    }else
        previouscale = 1;

    sender.scale = 1.0;

}
```